# How can I write multi line text in messages as simple?

Tags: java, playframework

I'm new for playframework.
and I read this tutorial.
http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1/i18n#messages

but I didn't understand how do I write multi line text to messages for i18n.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That looks like a property file. Try using a backslash (`\`) and continue on the next line.

```
hello=line 1\
line2
back=Back
```

or use `\n` as a new-line character.

From the documentation:

> If a logical line is spread across several natural lines, the backslash escaping the line terminator sequence, the line terminator sequence, and any white space at the start of the following line have no affect on the key or element values.

Comment: This does not seem to work in Play 2.0. And I've not tested in Play 1, but sometimes one needs to be aware that leading whitespace might be removed. If true for Play 1 too, then the above `line2` could be indented for readability. On the downsite, it might then also need some whitespace *before* the slash, as then even with leading indentation for `line 2` the end result might be `line 1line 2`. But again: I have not tested in Play 1.